# How to get the current database name in Impala? I actually googled a lot for this, but i didn't find anything related

Tags: sql, database, impala

I have a requirement to show the name of the TABLE NAME , DATABASE NAME and ROW COUNT of the given table using IMPALA, 
i am able to show the ROW COUNT  and TABLE NAME using below query and got stuck in getting current database name,I actually googled a lot but i didn't find anything related.
any one can help me in this?

```
select count(*) as rowcount,'table name' from table1
union
select count(*) as rowcount,'table name' from table2
union
select count(*) as rowcount,'table name' from table3
union
select count(*) as rowcount,'table name' from table4
```

Comment: you can use SHOW statement: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_show.html

Comment: By using SHOW , it is listing me all the available databases, but i want the current database, which the give table belongs to

Comment: SHOW TABLES [IN database_name] [[LIKE] 'pattern'] put database_name for your db. SHOW TABLE STATS table_name (put name of yor table)

Comment: @JoeTaras , database_name will not be the same all the time, i might run the report in SIT,DEV,PROD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-675 , you can use `select current_database()` to get the database name.